# How does Spellheart Chimera count Fuse or Split cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Spellheart Chimera](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spellheart%20Chimera). The creature gains +1/+0 for each sorcery or instant in the owners graveyard.

How does this work with such cards as [Far // Away](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369042)?

I've seen a few opinions on this matter, but cannot find an official ruling from WotC (or whoever hands down official rulings).

Can someone provide references to the official rulings, or the location of these rulings so I can look it up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If "Far // Away" was the only card in your graveyard, Spellheart Chimera would be 1/3**

Split cards always count as a single card:

> 708.2. Although split cards have two castable halves, each split card is only one card. For example, a player who has drawn or discarded a split card has drawn or discarded one card, not two.

Note that the Chimera asks for instant or sorcery *cards*, an important difference to just instant/sorcery. The latter only exists on the stack.

It would also count as a single card if the two halves had different types, for example if one half was instant and the other a sorcery.

Comment: They don't make half of a fuse card instant and half of a fuse card sorcery, do they? I'm not sure about the old split cards, but I'm pretty sure that all fuse cards are either instant/instant or sorcery/sorcery. That way they both have the same timing limitations. But either way, its still only +1/+0.

Comment: AFAIK the 2 halves of split cards always have the same type, true. It was a hypothetical anyway.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: The Amonkhet aftermath cards and newest Ravnica sets introduced [spilt cards of different types](https://scryfall.com/search?q=t:instant%20t:sorcery)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
My previous answer was wrong, but I will leave it so someone doesn't fall into the same trap I did.  The relevant rule is this:

> 708.6a Anything that performs a positive comparison (such as asking if a card is red) or a relative comparison (such as asking if a card’s
> converted mana cost is 3 or less) involving one or more split cards in
> any zone other than the stack or involving one or more fused split
> spells gets only one answer. This answer is “yes” if either side of
> each split card in the comparison would return a “yes” answer if
> compared individually.
>
> Example: Void reads, “Choose a number. Destroy all artifacts and
> creatures with converted mana cost equal to that number. Then target
> player reveals his or her hand and discards all nonland cards with
> converted mana cost equal to the number.” If a player casts Void and
> chooses 1, his or her opponent would discard Assault/Battery because
> its converted mana costs are 1 and 4. The same is true if the player
> chooses 4. If the player chooses 5, however, Assault/Battery would be
> unaffected.

Since at least one side is an instant or sorcery it gets back a yes answer and only counts as one.

<s>To quote one of the rulings from the Gatherer page for Far / Away (also rule 702.100b):</s>

> In every zone except the stack, split cards have two sets of
> characteristics and two converted mana costs. If anything needs
> information about a split card not on the stack, it will get two
> values.

So when the game goes to count the number of instant and sorceries in your graveyard for Spellheart Chimera power and gets to Far / Away it gets back that is is an instant twice and therefore counts it as two instants.

To give another example from the [Wizards FAQ on Dragon Maze rules](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/frequently-asked-questions-2013-04-22):

> In every zone except the stack, split cards have two sets of
> characteristics and two converted mana costs. If anything needs
> information about a split card not on the stack, it will get two
> values. For example, if a player reveals Down & Dirty due to
> Duskmantle Seer's ability ("At the beginning of your upkeep, each
> player reveals the top card of his or her library, loses life equal to
> that card's converted mana cost, then puts it into his or her hand."),
> the game will see its converted mana cost as 4 and 3. This translates
> to that player losing a total of 7 life.

Comment: Far//Away would return "Instant + Instant" when asked about its card type, but it's still a single card and will count as 1 for Chimera.

Comment: @Hackworth Then how come the Duskmantle Seer's ability gets back the **two** values 4 and 3 for a **total** of 7 damage and not 7 as a single value?

Comment: The card has two halves, each with its own mana costs, and you are correct that the mana costs would be added if something asked for its CMC. Hypothetically, if Far//Away had Instant on one half and Sorcery on the other, the whole card would count as as an "Instant Sorcery" card, adding the characteristics together. BUT it is still a single card, and when something such as the Chimera asks about the *number of cards* with a certain characteristic, not about the characteristic itself, split cards still only count as 1, even if both halves fulfill the condition.

Comment: @Hackworth Thanks for pointing that out.  I found the relevant rule and edited my answer appropriately.